# undefined reference to `vtable for class'

Tags: c++

.H file

```
#ifndef PROJECT_FILE_H
#define PROJECT_FILE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class File {
public:
    File();
    File(char *);
    File(const File&);
...
```

.CPP file

```
File::File(){ }
File::File(char *_t) : t(_t) {
    try {
        test();
    }
        catch (Exception &e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

}

File::File(const File &other): t(other.v1),t1(other.v2),t2(other.v3){ }
```

I get `undefined reference to vtable for File` error on each constructor. there is no pure virtual function definition in the class. the cmake file include both h/cpp files. What might be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: This is a crappy error message; it usually arises when you forget to provide bodies for virtual functions.  If the duplicate link does not help you then please edit your question to contain a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Error messages are not part of the C++ language. They are specific to a compiler. Please provide relevant information (compiler and version).

Comment: The error occurred because I forgot there was a virtual function in the code that was not defined.